# adding tab-bar controls on pushed UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

'M using story board and my project and is embedded with UINavigationController and TabBarController, the problem is when i try to push one of the UIViewController onclick of a button, the obtained UINavigationcontroller is without TabBarController buttons.

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Your Setup/Hierarchy should look like this

```
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UI"Whatever"ViewController
```

If you then push views in the `UI"Whatever"ViewController` your `NavigationBar` and your `TabBar` should stay.

Comment: Setup/Hierarchy1: UINavigationController -> UI"Whatever1"ViewController and Setup/Hierarchy2: UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UI"Whatever"ViewController   and m trying to push UI"Whatever2"ViewController from a button press in UI"Whatever1"ViewController.